# problema com o comportamento do google.maps.LatLngBounds

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Tenho e seguinte codigo que pecorre meus maker e seta os bouns

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

$.each(markers_temp, function (key, value) {
    markers[key] = value;
    bounds.extend(markers[key].position);
});

markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);

map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

ele funciona e faz o zoom e centraliza, e ai que esta o problema, porque quando tenho apenas pins colapsados, ou seja, na mesma coordenada o  map.fitBounds tenta centralizar o maximo possivel e ai não fica nada visivel.

Eu não queria que isso acontece, na verdade queria que os pins que fossem exatamente na mesma posição ficasse um pouco separados, mas não sei se isso é possivel, a não ser se for tratado na criação do maker ou antes na hora criação das minhas posições.

Se que é uma pergunta um pouco estranha, mas se alguem sabe alguma solução mais elegante?

**UPDATE**

Então usando a solução

```
function newMarker(lat, long, text_content, id, type) {
    if (markers[id]) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
        markers[id].setPosition(position);
        markers[id].set("type", "visible");
        markers[id].setMap(map);
    } else {
        if (type == 'sender') {
            image = image_sender;
        } else {
            image = image_deliver;
        }

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
            icon: image
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.close();
                infowindow.setContent(content_string);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                var position = marker.getPosition();
                map.panTo(position);
            }
        })(marker));

        var content_string = text_content;

        marker.set("type", "visible");

        markers_temp[id] = marker;
    }
}
```

essa função onde construo o meu maker colocando as posições dele no mapa, e colocando o conteúdo da informação.

```
function set_markers() {
    var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map);

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    $.each(markers_temp, function (key, value) {
        markers[key] = value;
        bounds.extend(markers[key].position);
        oms.addMarker(markers[key]);
    });

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

ele funciona perfeitamente;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe uma solução muito bacana que usei em um projeto, segue o link abaixo.

[Componente](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier)

Mas primeiro, veja se o exemplo abaixo se encaixa no seu problema.

[demo](http://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/demo.html)

Ele pega pontos com mesmo lat/lng e separa quando clica no cluster, assim o usuario pode selecionar um de cada vez.

Da um grito se precisar de ajuda.

Comment: Cara você poderia dar uma força? Fiz um update na questão, é isso mesmo o que eu quero fazer mas não esta dando certo.

Comment: deixa queto consegui

Comment: Grande Marcius, foi mais rapido que eu. rs :p parabens

Comment: Tenho um outro problema, tava vendo os parametros la que posso alterar, e não encontrei nenhum que aumentasse a distancia entre os pins quando abetos, porque eu alterei o tipo do meu pin para uma imagens, e ai mesmo quando eles abrem como aquela linha é curta eles ainda ficam um pouco sobre escritos.

Comment: achei os parâmetros olhando o codigo:
        nearbyDistance: 50,
        circleFootSeparation: 50,
        spiralLengthStart: 50